# Utility function with lambda for printing logging message

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

I am trying to write a utility function for house keeping the folder to be used in our application. Following is the definition of the function.

```
public static void housekeepFiles(File directoryToHouseKeep, Predicate<File> predicate, Logger logger, BatchLoggerService batchLoggerService){
    if(directoryToHouseKeep == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("directoryToHouseKeep cann't be null");
    if(logger != null) logger.info("Housekeeping the folder: " + directoryToHouseKeep.getAbsolutePath());
    File[] files = directoryToHouseKeep.listFiles();
    for(File file : files){
        boolean b = predicate.test(file);
        if(logger != null) logger.info("File should be house kept: " + b);

        if(predicate.test(file)){
            try {
                Files.delete(file.toPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if(logger != null) logger.error("Error while deleting the file: " + file.getAbsolutePath(), e);
                if(batchLoggerService != null) batchLoggerService.error("Error while deleting the file: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " because of: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem i am facing is the logging will be different in each execution. Mean callers wants to implement different kind of logging(Message to be printed).

I am thinking of providing two Consumer API(Java 8 lambda), so that caller can implement the actual logging. But I want the message to have the status of the individual file status(file path and whether it deleted or not) to be printed with the logging message. If i provide the functional interface, is there are any way to provide the variable in the local function scope(file) to be provided to caller. So that he can construct the whole message.

I know it sound stupid, but just checking any possibility?

Appreciate you advise.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking whether variables you get as arguments of function will be accessible inside lambda?

Comment: Don’t stay stuck with the `Consumer` interface. Think about, e.g. `BiConsumer<String,File>`…

Comment: @bartac, My question was misleading for you. Sorry for that. I was asking about exposing the variable inside the function to the lambda. I wrongly got the idea of lambda expression. Managed to do it with TriConsumer.

Comment: @Holger, Thanks for the suggestion. I used TriConsumer to solve the issue.

Comment: Off-topic, but you may want to check the result of listFiles() for null before the iteration to avoid a NPE if there is an I/O error.